# How to check values in each cell from one column to each cell in another column

Tags: excel, comparison, excel-2007, vba

I got 2 set of values and i need to highlight common values (alphanumeric) from 2 columns. Number of rows is in excess of 50,000 rows.  Any way to write a code for it?  Basicly, i need to check each cell from Col A  against each Cell from Col I from A2 to A59000

Comment: Just to clarify, if a value exists in both columns, you want to highlight it in both columns.  If it only exists in one column, do nothing with it. Is that correct?

Comment: How many different values do you have (estimate)? Are the columns sorted? Did you write the brute force code (2 nested loops)?

Answer (score 0):

An idea: use the VBScript Dictionary to avoid Rows * Rows loopings and a module for your experiments:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
' needs Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (for Dictionary)

Option Explicit

Const cnRows = 1000
Const cnLChar = 80
Const cnFNum = 1000
Const cnLNum = 1100

Function IntRange(iFrom, iTo)
    IntRange = iFrom + Fix((iTo - iFrom) * Rnd())
End Function

Sub fill()
    Dim sngStart As Single
    sngStart = Timer
    Dim sheetTest As Worksheet
    Set sheetTest = Sheet2
    Dim nRow, nCol
    For nRow = 1 To cnRows
        For nCol = 1 To 2
            sheetTest.Cells(nRow, nCol) = Chr(IntRange(65, cnLChar)) & IntRange(cnFNum, cnLNum)
        Next
    Next
    With sheetTest.Cells.Interior
       .ColorIndex = 0
       .Pattern = xlSolid
       .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    sheetTest.Cells(nRow, 1) = Timer - sngStart
End Sub

Sub bruteForce()
    Dim sngStart As Single
    sngStart = Timer
    Dim sheetTest As Worksheet
    Set sheetTest = Sheet2
    Dim nRow1 As Integer
    Dim nRow2 As Integer
    For nRow1 = 1 To cnRows
        For nRow2 = 1 To cnRows
            If sheetTest.Cells(nRow1, 1) = sheetTest.Cells(nRow2, 2) Then
               With sheetTest.Cells(nRow1, 1).Interior
                    .ColorIndex = 8
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
               End With
            End If
        Next
    Next
    sheetTest.Cells(nRow1, 1) = Timer - sngStart
End Sub

Sub useDict()
    Dim sngStart As Single
    sngStart = Timer
    Dim sheetTest As Worksheet
    Set sheetTest = Sheet2
    Dim dicElms As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim nRow As Integer
    For nRow = 1 To cnRows
        dicElms(sheetTest.Cells(nRow, 1).Text) = 0
    Next
    For nRow = 1 To cnRows
        If dicElms.Exists(sheetTest.Cells(nRow, 2).Text) Then
           With sheetTest.Cells(nRow, 2).Interior
                .ColorIndex = 8
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
        End If
    Next
    sheetTest.Cells(nRow, 2) = Timer - sngStart
End Sub
```

Comment: @kevin i got 58000 rows by 14 columns, with 2 columns(Col A & Col I) having same values(unique) but in different order (Col A-H as set 1, Col I-O as Set 2). Now I need to highlight the values from Col A with Col I.  Sample Values as I have
Col  A                       Col B
Os.20617.1.S1_at        Os.20617.1.S1_at
Os.12345.1.S1_s_at      Os.27061.2.A1_x_at
Os.20572.2.S1_at        Os.54653.1.S1_at
Os.10435.1.S1_at        Os.47388.1.S1_s_at

Estimated common values is 48000 from 58000 rows

Comment: @Ekkehard.Homer: I see you like to test your code's runtime. You're aware that most of it will be due to your looping through cells, right? And that you could speed your code up by an order of magnitude+ by loading the whole range into a Variant array and doing your processing there instead? The only other time you should access cells is to color the relevant ones.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: As the first loop accesses the cell value just once to put it into the dictionary and the second loop can't be avoided, the runtime difference is in an order of zilch.